# read more excerpt wordpress

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink

I have reviewed the other posts similar to my questions but I must be missing a something. 
I have added excerpts to my page like so:

```
[title size="2"]LATEST ARTICLES[/title]
[recent_posts columns="4" number_posts="12" cat_id="" thumbnail="yes"  excerpt="yes" title="yes"] [/recent_posts]
```

I am trying to do two things

1. set the length of the excerpt
2. make it link to the article (not necessarily a read more link the dots are fine)

I have tried to add the excerpt manually to the excerpt area (screen options) for the page but that is not overwritting what Wordpress is pulling from.

in my function.php file I am using

```
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'do_shortcode');
```

which works, but when I tried to add additional code below it does not do anything. Do I need to modify anothe rphp file to get this to register?

```
`enter code here`function new_excerpt_more($more) {
return '<a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . ' read on ..' . '</a>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');

function new_excerpt_length($length) {
return 46;
}
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'new_excerpt_length');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved your desired result w/ the following code ([from the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt)):

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
  return 46;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );

function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
  return ' <a class="read-more" href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '">' . __('Read More', 'your-text-domain') . '</a>';
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more' );
```